# Audio record while playing local audio file (Android)

Tags: android, audio, record, exoplayer

Let say I have a wav file local, it is kind of beat music, and then I play this file using ExoPlayer, I also sing a song at the same time. Is there any way to record audio at that time?
Then the recorded audio will include my voice and the beat music.